# Font ligatures and kerning break under selection in Swings text based components

Tags: java, swing, fonts, kerning, ligature

## Ligatures

Playing around with swing on java 17 I encountered some funky glitches: When enabling font ligatures and switching to a ligature heavy font, like `Fira Code`, selecting part of the ligated Text has following effect:

- The selected text seems to be re-rendered out of context, however the parts outside the ligature still are unchanged.

[image: Example of broken ligature]

- When exiting the selection the caret (text cursor) leaves some unrendered space between letters.

[image: Unselecting part of ligature leaves unrendered space]

- Both problems can also happen simultaneous, possibly leading to unreadable content.

[image: Both problems showing simultaneously]

## Kerning

When considering a kerning intensive font like `Segoe UI` or `Segoe UI Variable`, the new default font of Microsoft Windows 11, following glitches are happening:

- Re-rendering of selected text without kerning being calculated in the context of the full text.

[image: Animation of kerned rerendered selection]

- Trying to place the caret in a long line of kerned text (in this case the text is rendered more condensed) is nearly impossible - it seems like the internal selection logic is calculating the target based on the unkerned version.

[image: Animation of faulty selection offset for kerned text]

- Kerned text does also seem to have the problem of not being correctly re rendered when selections are canceled.

[image: Animation of Unselecting kerned text leaves artefacts of unrendered space]

## Analysis

The behaviour seems to show from at least Java 1.8 on, I spared my time and harddrive space checking previous versions. Also different LAF's do not seem to influence the glitches in any way. I think the culprit seems to be `java.desktop/javax.swing.text.PlainView`, especially its way in treating text as splittable segments, re rendering only 'damaged' text in `updateDamage#668` and its calculations of change bounding boxes.

## Workaround

The only consistent workaround I found working all the time was to deactivate kerning and ligatures. I also tried to hook my own PlainView class into swing, but its architecture actively tries to discourage such fixes.

## Questions

Finally I want to ask some questions, it would be very helpful in understanding the problematic:

- Did you also encounter such problems or is my fabricated example too synthetic?
- Are other rendering pipelines also affected? I assume so but I only was able to test on Windows 11.
- Do you know if it is the fault of the JVM standard library or are the stored font metrics non-standard?
- Are there any workarounds you know of improving the situation?
- Is there a way in exchanging the default font rendering pipeline in swing?

Thank you for your help! I have attached the source code as well as my current machine configuration below.

---

*Edit:*
The Problem also seems to be present on Mac OSX Big Sur and Java 17 leading to artefacts when using kerning and ligatures. To reproduce I used the default `Helvetica` font. This may hint on the cause for the glitches being the jdk.

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.font.*;
import java.util.*;


/**
        Tested on: Edition Windows 11 Pro
        Version    22H2
        OS build   22623.875
        Experience Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22636.1000.0
        
        openjdk 17.0.4.1 2022-08-12
        OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.4.1+1 (build 17.0.4.1+1)
        OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.4.1+1 (build 17.0.4.1+1, mixed mode, sharing)
**/
public class Main {
    private static final boolean TEST_KERNING = true;
    private static final boolean TEST_LIGATURES = true;
    private static final String TEST_FONT = "Segoe UI Variable";
    private static final Number TEST_FONT_SIZE = 40;
    private static final Number TEST_FONT_WIDTH = TextAttribute.WEIGHT_BOLD;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

        Map<TextAttribute, Object> textAttributes = new HashMap<>();
        textAttributes.put(TextAttribute.FAMILY, TEST_FONT);
        textAttributes.put(TextAttribute.SIZE, TEST_FONT_SIZE);
        textAttributes.put(TextAttribute.WEIGHT, TEST_FONT_WIDTH);
        if(TEST_KERNING)
            textAttributes.put(TextAttribute.KERNING, TextAttribute.KERNING_ON);
        if(TEST_LIGATURES)
            textAttributes.put(TextAttribute.LIGATURES, TextAttribute.LIGATURES_ON);
        Font font = Font.getFont(textAttributes);

        JTextField txtInput = new JTextField();
        txtInput.setFont(font);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");
        frame.setSize(400, 100);
        frame.add(txtInput);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(() ->
            frame.setVisible(true)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be interesting to repeat the test with JavaFX or Apache Pivot.  I use the Dialog font with Java 1.8 on Windows 10, but I don't do a lot of text processing with Swing.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc AFAIK does JavaFX not support font kerning and ligatures in its default components.

Comment: I don't know.  Font kerning is a subject I've never studied.

Comment: Swing text components don't support ligatures, kerning, or fractional metrics. You can, however, implement your own `ViewFactory` to return custom views which perform all the calculations taking ligatures and kerning into account. You can also submit a bug at bugreport.java.com.